# How can I add the bootstrap-material-design package into webpack?

Tags: webpack, angular-material, bootstrap-material-design

Im trying to add the bootstrap-material-design with webpack using also the bootstrap-loader based on Sass, but without results.

I can load it using bower-webpack plugin, but I want to have more control of it using npm without manage bower packages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, you should do, as @jkukul said:

> Install bootstrap-material-design:
>   `npm install --save bootstrap-material-design`
>   Add css loader to your webpack config:
>   `module.exports = {
>   module: {
>       loaders: [
>         { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
>       ]
>     },
>   };`

also, you should install **style-loader** and **css-loader** packages

```
 npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

and add extract text webpack plugin:

```
npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin --save
```

add this line **before module.exports**:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require ('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
```

and add this param **inside module.exports**:

```
styleLoader: require('extract-text-webpack-plugin').extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader')
```

probably, it would appear *jQuery undefined error* :
I fixed it that way

```
npm i jquery --save
```

and add plugins inside module.exports:

```
plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: "jquery",
     jQuery: "jquery"
})]
```

here is my total webpack.config file (hope it will be helpful!):

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require ('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  styleLoader: require('extract-text-webpack-plugin').extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!less-loader'),
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
    ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
         $: "jquery",
         jQuery: "jquery"
    })

  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    }

  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','.css'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
  }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps.

Install `bootstrap-material-design`:

```
npm install --save bootstrap-material-design
```

Add css loader to your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
 module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
    ]
  },
};
```

In your webpack's entry file add:

```
require('bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.css')
```

Comment: Do you know how to include sass version of this package?